# How to change multi dimensional hash value into json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a hash value in my table column backend_notes and I need to change this hash into json format.

```
{"school_id"=>"6", "accounts_response"=>"{\"type\"=>\"success\", \"message\"=>\"Updated Courses for 56789\"}", "courses
_not_found"=>"[{\"term\"=>\"FALL 2019\", \"dept_code\"=>\"ACCT\", \"dept_name\"=>\"ACCOUNTING\", \"course_code\"=>\"102\", \"course_name\"=>\"ELEM
ENTARY ACCT\", \"section_code\"=>\"000\", \"status\"=>\"new\", \"id\"=>20379}]"}
```

I tried the below migration command to change hash to json

```
change_column :carts, :backend_notes,'jsonb USING CAST(backend_notes AS jsonb)'
```

but this migration changed like this below format.

```
{"school_id":"6", "accounts_response":"{\"type\"=>\"success\", \"message\"=>\"Updated Courses for 56789\"}", "courses
_not_found":"[{\"term\"=>\"FALL 2019\", \"dept_code\"=>\"ACCT\", \"dept_name\"=>\"ACCOUNTING\", \"course_code\"=>\"102\", \"course_name\"=>\"ELEM
ENTARY ACCT\", \"section_code\"=>\"000\", \"status\"=>\"new\", \"id\"=>20379}]"}
```

My expected output is like below

```
{"school_id":"6","accounts_response":{"type":"success","message":"Updated Courses for 56789"},"courses_not_found":{"term":"FALL 2019","dept_code":"ACCT","dept_name":"ACCOUNTING","course_code":"102","course_name":"ELEMENTARY ACCT","section_code":"000","status":"new","id":"20379"}}
```

Comment: The values for the keys `accounts_response` and  `courses_not_found` aren't Ruby hashes or array with nested hashes. But they are strings with a string representation of Ruby hashes or arrays. When your expected output is JSON hashes and array, then you have to store those nested values as hashes or arrays but not as strings. Where is the data coming from, why were those values stored as strings in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your response @spickermann, Those are previously stored data. I changed the current code to store it as a direct JSON value but I need to change the previously stored record to convert it as JSON by using a new migration. do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash value from your DB includes values that are string representations of Ruby objects (arrays and hashes). To fully translate those values to JSON you need to translate the strings into Ruby objects first.

A very simple way might be to replace the `=>` with `:` and use a JSON parser to do the translation. It depends on the internal structure if that works or if you need more complex logic to fix those values. I would start with a helper method like this:

```
value = {"school_id"=>"6", "accounts_response"=>'{"type"=>"success", "message"=>"Updated Courses for 56789"}', "courses_not_found"=>'[{"term"=>"FALL 2019", "dept_code"=>"ACCT", "dept_name"=>"ACCOUNTING", "course_code"=>"102", "course_name"=>"ELEM ENTARY ACCT", "section_code"=>"000", "status"=>"new", "id"=>20379}]'}

# helper method
require 'json'

def string_parse_to_hash(string)
  modified_string = string
    .gsub(/:(\w+)/){"\"#{$1}\""}
    .gsub('=>', ':')
    .gsub("nil", "null")
  JSON.parse(modified_string)
rescue
  {}
end

# translate strings values to Ruby objects
value['accounts_response'] = string_parse_to_hash(value['accounts_response'])
value['courses_not_found'] = string_parse_to_hash(value['courses_not_found'])

value
#=> {
      "school_id"=>"6",
      "accounts_response"=>{"type"=>"success", "message"=>"Updated Courses for 56789"},
      "courses_not_found"=>[
        {"term"=>"FALL 2019",
          "dept_code"=>"ACCT",
          "dept_name"=>"ACCOUNTING",
          "course_code"=>"102",
          "course_name"=>"ELEM ENTARY ACCT",
          "section_code"=>"000",
          "status"=>"new",
          "id"=>20379
        }
      ]
    }

# translate to JSON
value.to_json
#=> "{\"school_id\":\"6\",\"accounts_response\":{\"type\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Updated Courses for 56789\"},\"courses_not_found\":[{\"term\":\"FALL 2019\",\"dept_code\":\"ACCT\",\"dept_name\":\"ACCOUNTING\",\"course_code\":\"102\",\"course_name\":\"ELEM ENTARY ACCT\",\"section_code\":\"000\",\"status\":\"new\",\"id\":20379}]}"
```

Comment: It should be noted the you DO NOT want to manually convert the data to JSON when dealing with JSON or JSONB columns as the database driver will handle it for you. That will just give you a string instead of actual JSON objects and you'll have to do the whole job of casting garbage data over again...